# Need to run deploy step only if triggered or started from web on branch master

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Need to run gitlab pipeline job only if it is triggered or run manualy on master. If run manual on other than master branch, job should be ignored. If triggered - than app is deployed from branch and later branch is merged to master. Merging to master causes one more deploy in my case. Need to avoid redundant deploy step.

Build triggered on any branch - run job
Build started manually on master branch - run job
Build started manually on other than master branch - skip job

In this case job runs twice: when triggered and when merged to master.

```
deploy-production:
  stage: deploy
  script: echo 1
  when: on_success
  only:
    - triggers
    - master
```

Need to ignore this step when deployed branch is pushed to master.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to use tags.
'only' and 'except' keywords in gitlab ci accepts branches and tags.

Since tags cannot be duplicated, you would need to use a new tag each time (live version.deployed.i where i is incremented each time) and use a regular expression on an except statement like

```
except: /^version.deployed./
```

Or use a 'deployed' tag that you delete and reuse each time you deploy.

Of course, your deploy job would need to handle the tagging once deployed.